# Get metadata is not defined

Tags: python

I am new to python. When I call getMetaData from the getattr method, I get an error that getMetaData is not defined. getMetaData is defined in the same class as getattr and when I comment out the call to getMetaData, there is no error. I get an error even if I move getMetaData above the definition of getattr. Why can't getattr see getmetadata?

Here is the code:

```
def getattr(self, path, fh=None):
    print('get attr' + path)
    full_path = self._full_path(path)
    if path.find('catvid') != -1:
        print 'te'
        getMetaData()
        full_path = '/home/memsql/Fuse/catvid.mp4'
        st = os.lstat(full_path)
        return dict((key, getattr(st, key)) for key in ('st_atime', 'st_ctime',
                 'st_gid', 'st_mode', 'st_mtime', 'st_nlink', 'st_size', 'st_uid'))
    else:
        st = os.lstat(full_path)
        return dict((key, getattr(st, key)) for key in ('st_atime', 'st_ctime',
                 'st_gid', 'st_mode', 'st_mtime', 'st_nlink', 'st_size', 'st_uid'))

def getMetaData():
    print 'hiya'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call it as:

```
self.getMetaData()
```

Otherwise Python will look for a global function named `getMetaData` and will raise `NameError`.

```
def func():
    print 'global'
...     
>>> class A:
...     def func(self):
...         print 'class'
...     def f(self):
...         func()        #calls global func()
...         self.func()   #calls A.func(self)
...         
>>> A().f()
global
class
```

Comment: When I use self.getMetaData I get an error TypeError: getMetaData() takes no arguments (1 given). How do I fix this?

Comment: @akh2103 Post `getMetaData()` in question body, looks like you've defined it as a staticmethod.